# Incorrect datetime format 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ'

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert this tring into a datetime object so I can remove the timezone. I am using the strptime function to turn it into a datetime object
`createdAt = datetime.strptime(createdAt, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ')`. However, even though this looks correct I still get the error: `ValueError: time data '2020-11-26T18:53:09.284Z' does not match format 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ'`. After I do this I plan to use the code `createdAt = createdAt.replace(tzinfo=None)` to replace the timezone info. Can someone tell me how my format is incorrect?

Comment: `datetime.strptime(createdAt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')` works for me.

Comment: Apparently, that's not the correct formatting for `strptime`. See [some docs](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) or this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: @ChrisCharley Thank you